# JNLP File upload and download fails

Tags: jnlp

I had start my java app from web site with the help of **JNLP**. But i am facing file upload and downloading problem.If i click upload button it doesn't give any response.

My code id below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0"
      codebase="http://localhost:8080/" 
      href="apprun.jnlp">
   <information>
      <title>Run Desktop app</title>
      <vendor>ACB </vendor>
   </information>
   <resources>     
    <jar href="apprun.jar"/>   
    <j2se version="1.6.10+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
    s java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>
   </resources>
   <application-desc main-class="apprun.mainclass"/>
</jnlp>
```

This apprun.jar is a desktop application. It have file upload and download functions.When i try it as a desktop app its works fine but when i try it in **JNLP** concept its fail.The file upload window not opening its doesn't show any error and not show any response.

Comment: if it's urgent, hire someone. I might come back to this after helping people with better time management skills.

Answer (score 0):

Your jnlp file is broken.

1.)
What is the **s** in the j2se tag?

`<j2se version="1.6.10+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
       s java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>`

2.) Put the `<j2se>` tag before any `<jar>` tags

Comment: i put <j2se> tag before all jar tag and remove s from <j2se> tag now i click get button for upload file it doesn't show any response.

Comment: Did you open the java console? What does it say there? http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: And what does it say? Do you know that you can increase the log level? Set it to maximum (5).